# The tools version "15.0" is unrecognized

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I have created a project with **Visual Studio 2017** on my PC at home.
But when I try to open it with **[SharpDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpDevelop)** it says:

> "The tools version "15.0" is unrecognized."

My **SharpDevelop** is on a USB stick, so I use it on different computers. Is there a way to fix this or can I change the tool version somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on if you are using any feature specific to the 15 toolchain, but if you are not you should be able to open the `.csproj` with a text editor and change the tools version down to 14.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

If the above does not work for you, recreate the project in Visual Studio 2015; that will use the 14 tools version. You should be able to open the project in Visual Studio 2017 and in SharpDevelop.